# A question about minimal tensor product

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ and $B_n$ be C*-algebras. we can define a *-homomorphism $\pi: A\otimes( \Pi_{n} B_n)\to\Pi_{n} (A\otimes B_n) $ be $\pi(a\otimes(b_n)_n)=(a\otimes b_n)_n$, where $a\in A$ and $b_n\in B_n$($\otimes$ is minimal tensor product,). How to understand $\pi$ is not surjective if A is infinite dimensional? Please help me!

Comment: Why is it bounded in the minimal tensor product ? Is $A$ assumed to be nuclear ?

Comment: Consider $A=\mathbb{K}$ (the compact operators on a infinite-dimensional separable Hilbert space) and $B_n=\mathbb{C}$ for  $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Then check that $\pi$ is not surjective.

Comment: @toto.  Can you give me the details?

Comment: @Bingyang do you have the seloution meanwhile?

Comment: @Ypsilon. Sorry, I haven't.